# waagent fails to run while creating linux vhd with waagent for windows azure

Tags: linux, azure

I am following given upload-a-vhd help document to create my openSuse linux vhd:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/

After I installed linux agent (waagent), i am not able to launch waagent in the vhd. When I try "sudo waagent" it return an error and command never execute. I tried installing waagent multiple times in vhd but still problem persist.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issues](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforLinux/thread/56069321-29ba-4e76-a54a-fd56696ac99d) with OpenSUSE Linux agent as in OpenSUSE you will need to use sudo /usr/sbin/waagent instead of sudo waagent as the bash shell is not the default shell used in that Image right now.

Please try above and let me know if your problem is resolved.